# why does cross validation for RandomForestRegressor fail in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The input training or testing file format are as follows:

```
-1 1 11.10115101|u 11.10115101 |s 2 |reason k:0.116|pv pv1000|g 2230444827 |k k3|w k:0
-1 1 11.10115101|u 11.10115101 |s 0 |reason c:0.080|pv pv1000|g 2235873129 |k k0|w c:1
-1 1 11.10115101|u 11.10115101 |s 1 |reason h:0.054 o:0.073|pv pv1000|g 2236879382 |k k10|w h:1 o:21
-1 1 11.10115101|u 11.10115101 |s 0 |reason u:0.133|pv pv1000|g 2237638819 |k k5|w u:26
-1 1 11.10115101|u 11.10115101 |s 0 |reason o:0.086|pv pv1000|g 2237694729 |k k5|w o:11
-1 1 11.10115101|u 11.10115101 |s 2 |reason l:0.111|pv pv1000|g 2237821631 |k k3|w l:0
```

The codes are as belows, the load_data() function load the training data or test data into list of python dict and returns a tuple ([dict,...], [0,1,0...]):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--train', required = True, help='train file')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--test', required = True, help='test file')
ns = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
f = open(ns.train)
inputs, targets = load_data( f )

print >>sys.stderr, 'load finish'
vec = DictVectorizer()
train = vec.fit_transform( inputs)
print >>sys.stderr, 'dict vectorizer finish'

print >>sys.stderr, 'training'
clf = RandomForestRegressor()
clf.fit(train.toarray(), targets)


print >>sys.stderr, 'testing'
f = open(ns.test)
test_inputs, test_targets = load_data( f )
test = vec.transform(test_inputs)
print cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, test.toarray(), test_targets, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Training works fine, but when doing cross validation, the last line of the codes throw the  exception :

```
  File "randomforest.py", line 72, in <module>
    print cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, test.toarray(), test_targets, scoring='roc_auc')
  File "/Users/jerry/pkgs/vpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1152, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv)
  File "/Users/jerry/pkgs/vpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 517, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/jerry/pkgs/vpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 312, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/jerry/pkgs/vpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jerry/pkgs/vpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1058, in _cross_val_score
    y_train = y[train]
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I wrote the code as in manual examples, but failed.

Comment: Please always report complete tracebacks. Also what is `test_targets`? What is its type and its shape? Does it have the same number of samples as the `test_inputs` variable? Apparently it is invalid.

Finally cross validation is meant to be run on a development set for model selection. Usually it does not really make sense to run it on the final evaluation (test) set.

Comment: sorry, I add more codes.

Comment: You still don't provide any information on the nature of the `test_targets` variable: is it a numpy array, a python list, something else? It it's an array what are the `.shape` and `.dtype`?

Comment: test_targets is a python list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is matching the recently reported [issue #2508](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2508).

A workaround would be to call add:

```
test_targets = np.asarray(test_targets)
```

prior to calling `cross_val_score`.

Answer (score 0):

I use another way to cal auc like :

```
preds = clf.predict_proba(test)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve( test_targets, preds[:, 1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```