# parallel random forest in scikit-learn throw a exception

Tags: scikit-learn

My sklearn version is 0.14.1 with python 2.7 on linux Debian GNU/Linux 7.1

calling:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split = 10, n_estimators = 50 , n_jobs = 1) is ok
```

while calling:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split = 10, n_estimators = 50 , n_jobs = 5)
clf.fit(train.toarray(), targets)
```

throw the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
self.target(self.__args, *self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in handletasks
put(task)
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

After throwing a exception , the random forest's all process are all blocked

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of your data?

Comment: Actually the input data is the same format as the post,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265097/why-does-cross-validation-for-randomforestregressor-fail-in-scikit-learn. dtype is float.

Comment: But as `load_data` is not described in that post either there is no way to know the resulting shape. Please just call `print(train.shape)` and include the result in your description.

Comment: after call print(train.shape), the output is (500000, 2073)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the shape info, the dataset should be ~4GB (for single precision floats). This exception might be caused by a memory exhaustion while multiprocessing is serializing the data to pass it to the worker processes.

<del>To limit the number of memory copies, you can try to replace the `sklearn/externals/joblib` folder by a symlink or a copy of the `joblib` subfolder of the master branch of the joblib repo: https://github.com/joblib/joblib</del>

<del>The development version of joblib has been improved to use memory mapping for large input arrays. This might fix your problem.</del>

**Edit** the memory mapping support has landed in joblib 0.8+ and is included by default in scikit-learn 0.15+

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the new joblib version. Is there a way to split the data and run scikit-learn's  random forest in multi-machines? Any library supported?

Comment: It's possible (for instance with IPython.parallel) but there is no ready made library and combining sub-models is model class-specific too. I talk about about that in: https://github.com/ogrisel/parallel_ml_tutorial and http://vimeo.com/63269736